# Amazon EC2 packet loss causing connections to time out. How to retry without changing all the query code?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, amazon-ec2, c3p0

Is there a way to make C3P0 (or DBCP) automatically retry queries that fail due to network issues.  The code works fine but occasionally the following exception occurs (no specific query, happens to various queries, even a simple row count that occurs every few seconds so it definitely works but then suddenly fails:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor89.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3567)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3456)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3997)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2468)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2719)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1379)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.execute(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:989)
at com.outboundengine.database.ClickstreamIdentityDbo.insertIgnore(ClickstreamIdentityDbo.java:65)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out

at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:114)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:161)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3014)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3467)
... 31 more
```

I started running traceroute between app server and DB server every second and got a bunch of traces that look like following:

```
Wed Apr 17 15:52:41 UTC 2013
traceroute to XXX.XXXXXXXXXX.com (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ec2.internal (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)  0.352 ms  0.443 ms  0.418 ms
 2  ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ec2.internal (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)  0.588 ms ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ec2.internal (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)  0.625 ms ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ec2.internal (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)  0.543 ms
 3  ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ec2.internal (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)  0.867 ms ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ec2.internal (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)  33.166 ms  33.505 ms
 4  ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ec2.internal (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)  1.554 ms ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ec2.internal (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)  0.435 ms ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ec2.internal (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)  0.756 ms
 5  ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ec2.internal (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)  0.830 ms ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ec2.internal (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)  0.803 ms ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-202.ec2.internal (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)  1.107 ms
 6  * ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ec2.internal (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)  1.449 ms *
 7  ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ec2.internal (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)  0.715 ms ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-202.ec2.internal (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)  0.973 ms  1.240 ms
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ec2.internal (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)  0.445 ms
```

...
(and many more of these during the 'outage' interval which lasts 10-60 seconds but it takes the connection 10 minutes to time out).

C3P0 config as follows:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/somename"
    auth="Container"
    factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
    type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    maxPoolSize="100"
    minPoolSize="10"
    acquireIncrement="10"

    automaticTestTable="testtable"
    testConnectionOnCheckin="true"
    idleConnectionTestPeriod="600"

    user="XXX"
    password="XXX"
    jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXXXXX:3306/dbname?autoReconnect=true"
  />
```

Each traceroute set with * in different places during the time the exceptions happen.
This is running on Amazon EC2 (at virginia location which is notorious for high packet loss which results in these time outs).
The code is simple JDBC queries backed by C3P0 db connection pool (and works perfect without network issues).
The C3P0 reconnected and all connection after time out, but timeouts take around 10 minutes to happen and everything returns back to normal when network stbilizes, but we get these outages at least once a day and queries get lost and need to be retried.

Is there a setting in the DB connection pool which would save me from changing all the queries in the code or do I have to write a simple loop that retries fails a few times before giving up?
Has anyone else had these problems with EC2 and found a solution?

Comment: are you doing any Connection testing? (i.e. what's your c3p0 config?)

Comment: periodic traceroute is how I am testing connection.  c3p0 config is attached.  C3P0 does fine in re-establishing connection after network is back to normal but when queries fail, I'd like to retry until they succeed.  The outages rarely last more than a minute and occur once or twice a day.  This is the US-EAST-1 data center which is their busiest and least reliable, so another option is to move to  the WEST one.  But query retries would be useful in any case.

Comment: no, i mean do you have c3p0 test Connections for you? http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

Comment: On checkin I do, on checkout their documentation says is a large hit to performance.  Also the connection may be good when it is acquired but when a query is to be sent packet loss will cause it to time out.  I did not find anything in the C3P0 docs that state it will retry a query a few times before failing for real.

Comment: so, c3p0 won't automaticaly retry queries of a checked out Connection; that'd be a pretty dangerous thing for it to do. checked-out Connections are the client's responsibility. c3p0 silently notes failures and tracks Statements/ResultSets for cleanup, but otherwise stays out of the way. you should be able to resolve your issue with good Connection testing. 1) testConnectionOnCheckout is over-dissed in the docs. it's terrible if you don't set an efficient preferredTestQuery, but often fine if you do, and very realiable; 2) if you use testConnectionOnCheckin, be sure you are also setting...

Comment: ...a tight idleConnectionTestPeriod to make sure that any Connection acquired from the pool has been very recently tested (so that window of client-visible failures is small). i recommend starting with testConnectionOnCheckout, then playing with combinations of testConnectionOnCheckin/idleConnectionTestPeriod as an optimization if desired. testConnectionOnCheckout is simple and reliable, but it does exact a cost that may or may not matter. as a general matter, c3p0 can help you when clients are pooled, but you're on your own when they're checked out. it's best to keep...

Comment: your Connection use arcs as brief as possible &mdash; get the Connection, do your business, close that Connection &mdash; to minimize the likelihood of failures that the pool can't help you with. the pool should be able to recover from database outages promptly as long as it is detecting failures promptly with a reliable Connection testing regime. I have now thoroughly abused StackOverflow comments!